# Restricting an npm dependency module's usage of require (isolation)

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, npm, require

Is there a way to `require` an npm module by restricting its usage of `require`?

For example, an app can offer a system to extend some of its features by providing (*as an upload maybe*) an npm module that fulfill a given contract (*say it exports a class with a method `process`*). That module, if it knows the source code of the app that will `require` it may `require('db').connect().flush()` or something alike.

This app extension may `require` anything from its host an modifies it. Does npm allow a restriction / security approach to handle this sort of case (maybe by using processes)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Neither Node.js nor npm do not provide tools to sandbox a module. Though with a little bit of knowledge of how a module is actually loaded we could easily implement such a mechanism.

Let's see, how a module [gets access to `require`](http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/06/require-and-the-module-system/#module-compile:1c7b09539349d942ecfae4f79bc4defd):

> Once require is ready, the entire loaded source code is wrapped in a new function, which takes in require, module, exports, and all other exposed variables as arguments. This creates a new functional scope just for that module so that there is no pollution of the rest of the Node.js environment.

Actually, we can see the exact template in the [source code](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/894203dae39c7f1f36fc6ba126bb5d782d79b744/lib/internal/bootstrap_node.js#L419-L422):

```
NativeModule.wrapper = [
    '(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { ',
    '\n});'
];
```

So we can leverage the same approach by wrapping the uploaded module in IIFE *before requiring it*:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {

    // module source

}(exports, undefined /* here's the trick */, module, __filename, __dirname);
```

Now we can safely require wrapped module, as it has not access to `require` function anymore.

Answer (score 0):

NPM does not provide anything to accomplish this, but depending on your requirements you could achieve some level of security by overriding node's require statement.

```
const MY_SECRET_TOKEN = '1234';
const rekuire = global.require;
global.require = function(nodeModule, token) {
  if (nodeModule !== 'db' || MY_SECRET_TOKEN === token) {
    return rekuire(nodeModule);
  }

  throw new Error('Unauthorized attempt to access secure module "db"!); 
};
```

A malicious module could still work around this. Realistically your focus should be on carefully vetting what module you use, I wouldn't ever use above in prod.